# How do I make an 3 images with bottom information

Tags: html, css, image

I want to make something a bit like this

[image]

But with styling

```
<style>

    .wrapper {
        border: 10px solid #897ee6;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 0;
        background-color: #e68e7e;
    }
    .wrapper img {
        height: 32%;
        width: 32%;
        grid-column: 1;
        border: 5px solid #e67ee6;
        display: inline-flex;
        position: static;
        background-size: 10px;
    }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="/home/RG/image/computerIMGedit.jpg" />
<div class="content1">
</div>
<img src="example.jpg">
<img src="example.jpg">
    .content1 {
        height: 300px;
        background: #e3c88d;
        width: 30%;
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding: 0;

            }
</style>
```

But then ends up looking like this

[image]

So I decided to see if the same thing happened with the text, and it does! How can I possibly make the content look like the first image?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will do what you want.
Your need make division containing image and description. These divisions need `float:left` so that they gets displayed side by side. Look into the code. It may help you understand more.

```css
div.gal {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  color: #111;
  background: #aaa;
}
div.gal:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
div.gal img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
div.cont {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gal" style="background:#faa">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDMSV.png" width="600" height="400">
  <div class="cont">Notepad Sticky</div>
</div>
<div class="gal" style="background:#afa">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDMSV.png" width="600" height="400">
  <div class="cont">Notepad Sticky</div>
</div>
<div class="gal" style="background:#aaf">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDMSV.png" width="600" height="400">
  <div class="cont">Notepad Sticky</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use the HTML CSS snippet for your code? then it's easier to run it.

Comment: You can run and check it now. @SørenEriksen

Comment: If anyone can say why the answer is showing "-1" it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS-grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) to your advantage

An example of this could be:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 10px solid #897ee6;
  display: grid;
  background-color: #e68e7e;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 45px;
}

.wrapper div {
  border: 5px solid #e67ee6;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    <p> example text
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    <p> example text
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    <p> example text
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the `1fr` unit means 1 fraction meaning that since there's three of them each div will take up a third

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex`:

```css
.horizontal {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.horizontal > div {
    flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal">
        <div>
            <img src="/home/RG/image/computerIMGedit.jpg" />
            <p> example text</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="/home/RG/image/computerIMGedit.jpg" />
            <p> example text</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="/home/RG/image/computerIMGedit.jpg" />
            <p> example text</p>
        </div>
</div>
```